# Parse Cloud Code Error: success/error was not called (Code: 141, Version: 1.9.0)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

What is wrong with this code?:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("insertCouponReview", function(request, response){

var ReviewClass = Parse.Object.extend("Review");
var newReview = new ReviewClass();

var CouponClass = Parse.Object.extend("Coupon");
var coupon = new CouponClass( { objectId: request.params.couponId });

var UserClass = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var user = new UserClass( { objectId: request.params.userId });

newReview.set( "couponId"       , coupon );
newReview.set( "userId"         , user);
newReview.set( "reviewTitle"    , request.params.reviewTitle);
newReview.set( "comment"        , request.params.comment );
newReview.set( "numberOfStars"  , request.params.numberOfStars);

newReview.save({
    sucess:function(  ){
        response.success("Ok");
    },
    error: function(){
        response.error("Erro");
    }
});
```

});

It save correctly on Parse. But I still got the error. x)
I'm new on JS and Parse Cloud Code...

Comment: Add the error in question also.

Comment: This is the only error: **[Error]: success/error was not called (Code: 141, Version: 1.9.0)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the typo `sucess` of the word `success` which leads to the save success block not being called.

```
newReview.save({
    sucess:function(  ){
        response.success("Ok");
    },
    error: function(){
        response.error("Erro");
    }
});
```

In particular, the problem is this line

```
sucess:function(  ){
```

Change it to this and you should be good to go.

```
success: function(){
```

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to upvote and mark as answer to close this out :)